# Why is my array that I get via ajax (js) empty (POST)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

When I send an array via ajax, the post key does not show up. The key links is not visible in the POST.

My js code:

```
function update() {
var linkArr = [];
linkKeys.forEach(key => {
    if ($('input[name="' + key['value'] + '"').length) {
        linkArr[key['value']] = [];
        $('input[name="' + key['value'] + '"]').each(function () {
            linkArr[key['value']].push(($(this).val()));
        });
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/update',
    data: {
         links: linkArr
        }
    });
}
```

My php code:

```
public function update(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $payload = $_POST;
            var_dump($payload);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Where do you expect it to show up? Your JavaScript isn't reporting anything about the response.

Comment: Please include the shape of `linkKeys` and also the code where `update` is being called.

Comment: @Quentin in my var_dump

Comment: Where, in your user interface, do you expect to see the output of `var_dump`?

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev For information. linkArr returns a complete and correct array in javascript via console.log.

Comment: @Quentin In my response of ajax.

If I add another key e.g. id, it appears in the POST as a response. Only links does not appear in the post.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea?